# Send values from child to parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to separate the inputs from being at the same component with the button so I put them at another component but the problem lies in accessing those states in the parent component so that I could catch them and use those value in submission, so how I can solve that?

```
export default function Parent() {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(name, email); // I wanna access those child states here
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Child() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  return (
    <form>
      <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so that it exists on the parent and gets passed down to the child, so that both can see and use it:

```js
function Parent() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(name, email); // I wanna access those child states here
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Child {...{ name, setName, email, setEmail }} />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function Child({ name, setName, email, setEmail }) {
  return (
    <form>
      <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create and handle hooks in parent component instead of the child component.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(name, email); // I wanna access those child states here
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Child name={name} email={email}
      setName={setName}
      setEmail={setEmail}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function Child(props) {
 const {name, email, setName,setEmail } = props;
  return (
    <form>
      <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-fast-ugy46?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the states in the parent component and pass the state and setState as props to child component, the responsibility of child component is to show what it is getting as input and call handler(that is setState passed down by parent in props) if there is change element

Answer (score 0):

Parent won't be able to directly access the state inside of Child.

One solution is to lift state up as advised by CertainPerformance's answer.

Another solution is to have the submit button inside of child and pass down a callback to access the input values on submit to avoid passing down so many different props.

````
export default function Parent() {
  const handleSubmit = (name,email) => {
    // do whatever you want with name and email here
    console.log(name, email);
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Child({onSubmit}) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  return (
    <form>
      <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={()=>onSubmit(name,email)}>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use props to pass down the parent function into the child. When the child form is submited, it'll call up to the parent. Alternatively you could lift the state as the other answer suggests, this is a good idea.

Be careful that the child component isn't handling the form submit, if the user presses enter in one of those textboxes it'll trigger a reload.

Something like this (not lifting state, but you could do that as well):

```
export default function Parent() {
  const handleSubmit = (name, email) => {
    console.log(name, email); // I wanna access those child states here
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Child({onSubmit}) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); onSubmit(name, email); }}>
      <input placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```